# Inserting a field to multiple regions

Tags: theming, 8

I have a content type with field_slides and I want to use it on multiple region in the same page. its a slide show using light gallery, at mobile view I want to hide the first div and show it on the second one.

```
<body>
<div class="first-div"> {{content.slides}} </div>
<div class="second-div">{{content.slides}} </div>
</body>
```

The issue is the slides works fine on the first div but if i try to open it on the second div it keeps scrolling  to the top ( first div )/reloading the page sometimes. However if I removed the region from the first div it works fine on the second div, I want to have it working on both the divs. Is this possible ?? please help

I also tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (($(window).width() < 701 )) {
    $(".first-div").empty();
    $(".second-div").append( "{{content.slides}}" );
   }
  else {
    $(".first-div").append( "{{content.slides}}" );
    $(".second-div").empty();
  }
});
</script>
```

Its not working either ---

Here is the actual twig template

```
{% set slider2 = content.content_2_project %}
   <body>
      <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section">
          <div class="portfolio-section1">
            <div class="port-top">
              {{content.content_1_project}}
              {{content.content_1_punch}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="section">
          <div class="portfolio-section2">
              <div class="port-left">
                <div class="port-left-inner">
                  {{content.content_2_body}}
                  {{content.content_2_body_details}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="port-right">
                <div class="port-right-slide-container">
                    {{content.content_2_project}}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section mobile-section">
          <div class="port-mob-slide-container">
                {{ slider2 }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

i'm using Fullpage.js on the drupal 8 site.

Comment: I told you add the result of markup rendering !!!!  JS?!!!! 
Drupal Theme engine is twig, I suggest you have look at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tricky method

```
{% set slider2 =content.slides %}
<body>
<div class="first-div"> {{content.slides}} </div>
<div class="second-div">{{slider2}} </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks ill try tomorrow now --- ill let you know if it work ... ill try removing div contents with jQuery too...

Comment: no it does not work --- the page keeps reloading if i click one second div images.

Comment: @TheNagaTanker it's seems strange, I do this trick several times on my project, is this solution render  slider field on second-div? (with getting help of inspect of broswer check it's markup)

Comment: i did its as you said -- ill check again

Comment: @TheNagaTanker for better debugging add Markup output of that section to the question.

Comment: just added the twig markup

Comment: inspect markup on browser, you don't add twig with jquery, they run ad processed on server side. twig is not client side technology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55517/discussion-between-zhilevan-and-the-naga-tanker).